# Was "bicycle" ever pronounced "bi-cycle" and if so where and when?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change

Was "bicycle" ever pronounced "bi-cycle" and if so where and when?

What's the source?

Comment: No. It has always been pronounced BAI-SI-KL in English. It comes from French 'bicycle' which was pronounced  /bi.sikl/ [[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bicycle#French)].

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Did French used to have the non-diminuative 'bicycle' but replce it with "bicyclette" at some stage?

Comment: @BoldBen: No clue. Wikitionary doesn't give much info about that

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be French in origin - at least, this is the first attested use in print. And it appears always to have been one word.

See here: https://www.etymonline.com/word/bicycle
and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle#Etymology

Comment: I think the question is more on pronunciation rather than the written form.

Comment: So ti was - beg pardon!